# HTML5 Vídeo local

Tags: html, html5

Tenho este código HTML para tentar reproduzir um vídeo que está no meu disco rígido. Quando eu abro o link da source diretamente no browser, ele reproduz sem problema, porém, usando este código:

```
<video width="750" controls>
  <source src="C:\FileUploads\VideoMails\1_559400305_teste.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

O player não carrega nada. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tenta colocar o html no mesmo diretório do arquivo mp4 e chame somente 1_559400305_teste.mp4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questão se segurança de protocolo, quando você abre o arquivo direto do diretório, você esta utilizando o protocolo file (file://c:/.....) que é o mesmo do source da sua tag de vídeo, porém quando você abre através do servidor, estará usando um protocolo http (ou https) no qual a página estará tentando acessar informações locais do cliente, que apesar de fisicamente serem os mesmos, por tipo de acesso são diferentes.
Copie o arquivo para o mesmo local que esta a sua página e use endereço relativo:

```
<video width="750" controls>
  <source src="./1_559400305_teste.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Ou crie um diretório virtual para os seus videos, e aponde para lá.